# Encourage pre-schooler to keep room clean

Tags: pre-schooler, bedroom, cleaning

My 4 year old's room is constantly a mess. Usually once a week, we tell him to stay in his room and clean up. He usually does a decent job of it with some help from us. But he generally lacks the interest to keep it maintained.

Are there any ideas to help encourage him to keep his room is neater? I realize he is only 4 and I am not expecting a spotless room by any means. Just a room we can at least walk into without tripping over 50 items on the floor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of [a weekly job fit only for Hercules](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/Herakles/stables.html), we incorporate clean-up into our daily bedtime routine: clean up, brush teeth, shower/bath, pyjamas, bedtime story, nighty-night.  It's not negotiable, it's communal (we all help clean up), and it's supervised (he can't play anymore once clean-up starts), so it goes fairly smoothly and is usually over in minutes.

And as a priceless bonus, you get to wake up every morning and stumble bleary-eyed to the kitchen *without* stepping on Legos along the way!

Answer (score 1):

try making it a game.... put music on, and dance.... maybe even something special at the end of the week if he keeps it clean, like going out for ice cream or whatever appeals to them.